# How to understand "self.addressList[self.current].name" used in the setAddress function

Tags: python, class, tkinter

***I explain my question more specifically below the end of the code.***

```
import pickle
import os.path
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class Adddress:
    def __init__(self, name, street, city, state, zipcode):
        self.name = name
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        
class AddressBook:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("AddressBook")
        
        self.nameVar = StringVar()
        self.streetVar = StringVar()
        self.cityVar = StringVar()
        self.stateVar = StringVar()
        self.zipcodeVar = StringVar()
    
        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        Label(frame1, text = 'Name').grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame1, textvariable = self.nameVar, width = 40).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        Label(frame2, text = 'Street').grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame2, textvariable = self.streetVar, width = 40).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame3 = Frame(window)
        frame3.pack()
        Label(frame3, text = 'City').grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame3, textvariable = self.cityVar, width = 10).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        Label(frame3, text = 'State').grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame3, textvariable = self.stateVar, width = 5).grid(row = 1, column = 4)
        Label(frame3, text = 'Zip', width = 5).grid(row = 1, column = 5, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame3, textvariable = self.zipcodeVar, width = 5).grid(row = 1, column = 6)


        frame4 = Frame(window)
        frame4.pack()
        Button(frame4, text = 'Add', command = self.processAdd).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        btFirst = Button(frame4, text = "First", command = self.processFirst).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        btNext = Button(frame4, text = "Next", command = self.processNext).grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        btPrevious = Button(frame4, text = "Previous", command = self.processPrevious).grid(row = 1, column = 4)
        btLast = Button(frame4, text = "Last", command = self.processLast).grid(row = 1, column = 5)

        self.addressList = self.loadAddress()
        self.current = 0

        if len(self.addressList) > 0:
            self.setAddress()

        window.mainloop()
        
        
    def saveAddress(self):
        outfile = open("address.dat", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.addressList, outfile)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Address saved", "A New address is saved")
        outfile.close()
        
    def loadAddress(self):
        if not os.path.isfile("address.dat"):  #if the file not exists
            return []
        
        try :
            infile = open("Address.dat", "rb")
            addressList = pickle.load(infile)   #get the data from the existed file to a list
        except EOFError:
            addressList = []   #read to the last one, or no data in the file
            
        infile.close()
        return addressList
    
     
    def processAdd(self):
        address = Address(self.nameVar.get(), self.streetVar.get(), self.cityVar.get(), self.stateVar.get(), self.zipcodeVar.get())
        self.addressList.append(address)
        self.saveAddress()
        
    def processFirst(self):
        self.current = 0
        self.setAddress()
        
    def processNext(self):
        if self.current < len(self.addressList) - 1:
            self.current += 1
            self.setAddress()
            
    def processPrevious(self):
        print("Left as exercise")
        
    def processLast(self):
        print("Left as exercise")
        
        
    def setAddress(self):
        self.nameVar.set(self.addressList[self.current].name)
        self.streetVar.set(self.addressList[self.current].street)
        self.cityVar.set(self.addressList[self.current].city)
        self.stateVar.set(self.addressList[self.current].state)
        self.zipVar.set(self.addressList[self.current].zip)
```

For the parameter passed to .set() method, how to understand the value of **self.addressList[self.current].name**, I see that the self instance refers to the object defined by the AddressBook class, but in the data fields of this class, there is no such ”name" which is actually defined in another class - Address. I can understand ***self.addressList[self.current]*** refers to an object in the AddressList. But in this class, I assume that the extra ***.name*** should not work to get the first property, which is the stored name, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`self.addressList` is a list of `Address`. When you call `self.addressList[self.current]`, you get the `Address` object at the position `self.current` in this list. On this `Address` object, you can ask for the `name` member. That's what `self.addressList[self.current].name` does.

Comment: Thank you! I figure that ***self.addressList[self.current]*** refers to an Address object, that's equivalent to self.name in terms of ***self.addressList[self.current].name***. :D

Comment: @ChenTang To be clear: `self.name` is valid in the `Address` class. While in the `AddressBook` class, to get the name of an `Address` object, you can't use `self.name`. A more easy way to look at it is `currentAddress = self.addressList[self.current]` and afterwards `currentAddress.name`.